# UserControl OnClick events never occur

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, onclick

I have a web project in C#/asp.net.  I have a UserControl with a GridView that has a Button coded into it.  The button has an OnClick event which will result in it a redirect to another page.  At this point in time, the onclick event never happens no matter how many times I press the button.  However, if I hardcode a button into the page that is using the user control (with the event in its code behind), the onclick events work perfectly fine.

Also, when I move the button outside of the UserControl's GridView, it works fine.  However, I am limited by space and need it to be placed in the pager bar along the bottom of the page.

```
<PagerTemplate>
     <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
           <td align="left" valign="middle">
              <asp:Panel cssClass="PagerPanel" runat="server">
                 <asp:Button ID="FirstButton" runat="server" OnClick="FirstButton_Click" Text="|&lt;"  Enabled="<%# (_gridView.PageIndex > 0) %>" />
                 <asp:Button ID="PrevButton" runat="server" OnClick="PrevButton_Click" Text="&lt;" Enabled="<%# (_gridView.PageIndex > 0) %>" />
                 <%# _gridView.PageIndex+1  %> of <%# _gridView.PageCount %>
                 <asp:Button ID="NextButton" runat="server" OnClick="NextButton_Click" Text="&gt;" Enabled="<%# (_gridView.PageIndex < _gridView.PageCount-1) %>" />
                 <asp:Button ID="LastButton" runat="server" OnClick="LastButton_Click" Text="&gt;|" Enabled="<%# (_gridView.PageIndex < _gridView.PageCount-1) %>" />
              </asp:Panel>
           </td>

           <td>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="AddButton_Click" runat="server"       
              Text="Button" />
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </PagerTemplate>
```

UserControl Code Behind:

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("thisurl...");
}
```

Not sure what else I can do to handle this click event.  Apparently the GridView is stopping it from firing somehow.  Is there anyway that a UserControl's GridView can have a button that will handle onclick events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add CommandName="Button" attribute to the asp:Button declaration and then wire up the the RowCommand event of the GridView.  Then, check for command name (i.e. if (e.CommandName == "Button") in the OnRowCommand event handler.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandName="Button" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

...

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Button")
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Brady! That is exactly what I needed. Added the property 
    "OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand" to the gridview and it worked great!

Comment: Ok it almost worked perfect.  The CommandName and CommandArgument is coming through as "Edit" & "-1" every time regardless of what I set the property to.  Is there any way around this?  I need a way of uniquely identifying which button was pressed so I know where to redirect.

Comment: That's strange.  Make sure the AutoGenerateEditButton property on the gridview is not set to true.  If you still can't get it to work, I would create a quick and dirty website with a button in a gridview and make sure you can get it work.  Then, you can, by process of elimination, figure out what is going on.  There might be some other stuff in your gridview that is interfering.

Comment: Found it!  I had an on row click function that was causing it to send the wrong CommandName, even though I wasn't clicking on the row.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because the events have to be bound to the control before the event handler can be executed, but because your button is dynamically added to the page by the template, it doesn't exist by the time the event is triggered.

There are many ways in which to fix this, but I would look into using EnsureChildControls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.ensurechildcontrols.aspx